# ArgumentNullException when calling an interface from a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, blazor

I'm trying to set up authorization by using policies because for some reason the ClaimsPrinciple doesn't work, so I'm trying this.

My current problem is that `service` is returning as null. I've tried `UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>();`, however it gives me an error.

```
public class AdminRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AdminRequirement>
{
    public bool Check = false;
    IServiceProvider service { get; set; }
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
                                      AuthorizationHandlerContext context, 
                                      AdminRequirement requirement)
    {
        var CurrentEmail = context.User.Identity.Name;
        string RoleName = requirement.ToString();
        await GetData(CurrentEmail, RoleName);
    }

    private async Task GetData(string CurrentEmail, string RoleName)
    {
        var UserManager = service.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(CurrentEmail);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var adminCheck = await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, RoleName);
            if (adminCheck == true)
            {
                Check = true;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The service property has not been initialized. You can do that by creating a constructor that accepts an IServiceProvider parameter.

```cs
public AdminRequirementHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    service = serviceProvider;
}
```

Comment: I've tried many different implementations of this kind of thing, but I couldn't get it to work. Either I put all those methods in the `AdminRequirementHandler(IserviceProvider serviceProvider)` constructor and the whole thing doesn't work, or the `service` doesn't get recognized anywhere.

Comment: If so it is you should add more context to your question. This should be not just a problem of the AdminRequirementHandler. Maybe it could be useful to include the code inside the Startup.cs file where you register your dependencies and where you configure the middlewares of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use dependency injection in .Net Core project.
More information you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: You mean write up all the code in the class and then inject that in to a startup?

Comment: First of all you need to implement your interface IServiceProvider. And, yes, then you can inject in to a startup.

Answer (score 0):

AuthorizationHandlerContext.Resource should be of type 
AuthorizationFilterContext. From which you can get the HttpContext and from that the RequestServices which is a ServiceProvider.